# How to programmatically set a slider that controls a image views width

Tags: swift, slider, nslayoutconstraint, func, viewdidappear

My code below is written in all code no storyboard. What I want to do use the slider move to change the width of the imageView pic. What I have tried below does not work. When the slider moves I want the width of pic to move along with it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pic = UIImageView()
    var move = UISlider()

    var oldCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    var box = 20
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        pic.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow

           [pic,move].forEach({
               $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               self.view.addSubview($0)
           })

        oldCons = [
               pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
               pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200),
               pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(box)),
               pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
            ]
           NSLayoutConstraint.activate(oldCons)

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
               move.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :37.5),
               move.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
               move.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
               move.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

           ])
           move.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func moveRight() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(oldCons)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :50),
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -50),
            pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(box)),
            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450)
        ])

        box = Int(CGFloat(20 + move.value*90))
        print(box)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of activating / deactivating constraint sets, add a `picWidthConstraint` as a class-level property:

```
    // we'll use this to dynamically change the pic width
    var picWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

then, when you want to change the width of `pic`, change the `.constant` of that constraint:

```
    box = Int(CGFloat(20 + move.value*90))
    print(box)
    picWidthConstraint.constant = CGFloat(box)
```

Here is your original class, with modifications (see the comments):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pic = UIImageView()
    var move = UISlider()

    // don't need this anymore
    //var oldCons = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    var box = 20

    // we'll use this to dynamically change the pic width
    var picWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        pic.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemYellow

        [pic,move].forEach({
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.view.addSubview($0)
        })

        // create pic.widthAnchor property (var)
        picWidthConstraint = pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(box))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            pic.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :150),
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : -200),

            // activate the pic width constraint
            picWidthConstraint,

            // don't create another one
            //pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(box)),

            pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450),

            // constraints for the slider
            move.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant :37.5),
            move.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant : 225),
            move.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            move.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

        ])

        // use .valueChanged to change the pic width *while* dragging the slider thumb
//      move.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .touchUpInside)
        move.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveRight), for: .valueChanged)

    }

    @objc func moveRight() {

        box = Int(CGFloat(20 + move.value*90))
        print(box)
        picWidthConstraint.constant = CGFloat(box)

    }

}
```